# BLE Application Peripheral Code on MCU DA14585 cannot be scanned by IOS but can with Android and Windows

Tags: c++, c

BLE Application Peripheral Code on MCU DA14585 cannot be scanned by IOS but can with Android and Windows.

MCU : Dialog DA14585
BD address is :

## define CFG_NVDS_TAG_BD_ADDRESS             {0x03, 0x00, 0x70, 0xCA, 0xEA, 0x80}

I follow example code from DA14585_SDK\6.0.10.511\projects\target_apps\ble_examples\ble_app_peripheral.

May I know what is going wrong?
Is it need to configure BD address?

Thank you.

Observation :
1. can scanned with Android and Windows.
2. cannot be scanned by Iphone/ Ipad IOS

## define CFG_NVDS_TAG_BD_ADDRESS      {0x03, 0x00, 0x70, 0xCA, 0xEA, 0x80}

Should be able be scanned by Iphone/ Ipad IOS as well.

Comment: Which OS you have does not effect the Bluetooth controller's ability to detect the Bluetooth signal. Which Bluetooth device address you have also doesn't matter. Try decrease advertising interval to increase the probability that the advertisement will be detected.

Comment: Hi Emil, Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Emil, yes, with decrease advertising interval, now the iOS can detect it. Thank you very much.